# NoSuchMethodError: org.thymeleaf.standard.StandardDialect with spring 4 and thymeleaf 3

Tags: thymeleaf, spring-4

Hi i'm using spring 4 with thymeleaf 3 for my project. I have changed everything according to their doc. When i run the application on wildfly 10 , it is showing some errors..

```
21:35:15,447 WARN  [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 9) Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'templateEngine' defined in class path resource [spring/ViewConfig.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.thymeleaf.standard.StandardDialect.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;I)V
21:35:15,458 ERROR [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 9) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'templateEngine' defined in class path resource [spring/ViewConfig.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.thymeleaf.standard.StandardDialect.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;I)V
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1105)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1050)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
```

Themeleaf3 dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.web.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

Template Resolver Configuration

```
<bean id="templateResolver"
        class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
        <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
        <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
        <property name="dialects">
            <set>
                <bean class="org.thymeleaf.standard.dialect.StandardDialect" />
                <bean class="nz.net.ultraq.web.thymeleaf.LayoutDialect" />
            </set>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
        <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you resolved this, but your post on here was the only result I was getting on the whole internet for this issue.

It took me several hours to finally find the cause for me.  For some reason I had the Thymeleaf 2.14-RELEASE jar within the /lib folder of my project.  My IDE (Intellij 2016.2.5) was using this version rather than the one with 3.0.5-RELEASE that maven had.  There was no obvious hint within the IDE that this was taking place.

The main issue was the StandardDialect from 2.14 had no constructors (hence the weird error) but the one in 3.0.5 does.

I was racking my brains as there was just no logical reason for this error and I hope this saves any poor soul out there.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problems I just removed all the extra `thymeleaf` dependencies and just added this to pom.xml and works for me.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem, it worked for me after I removed this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```